# How to unit test code which receives response from server

Tags: ios, swift, unit-testing, networking

I have a code fragment which I want to unit test , this code depends upon callback from network stack on event of receipt of data. The network calls are made through a library its basically amazon iOT library, thus I am not directly interacting with iOS network framework but this library. I want to unit test this code, not sure if its possible if yes how.

Attached is the code in question

```
static func subscribeForData(completionCallBack:((String,NSDictionary)->())?,errorCallBack:((NSError)->())?) {
    let iotDataManager = AWSIoTDataManager.default()
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    let login = .....

    iotDataManager.subscribe(toTopic: "testNode/device/"+login, qoS: .messageDeliveryAttemptedAtLeastOnce, messageCallback: {
        (payload) ->Void in
        let stringValue = NSString(data: payload, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)!
    })    
}
```

Comment: Try using this lib to mock the networking layer: https://github.com/AliSoftware/OHHTTPStubs (you can add json files and provide them as network responses for specific url calls)

Comment: My first thought will be dispatch semaphore, wherein it will wait until the server responds and you can signal the semaphore to continue

Comment: @Joshua Unit tests should be fast. Yo should **NOT** test for real networks calls.

Comment: I would prefer to mock the response instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way you can achieve this is through **Dependency Injection (DI)**.

DI can be used as a mean to inject both the real networking code and the "mocked" one.

In order to deal with DI you need to modify your code. In particular an instance of `AWSIoTDataManager` should be passed to `subscribeForData` method instead of hardcoding it (why do you have a `static` method?).

There are different approaches in order to deal with this. One is described for example in [The complete guide to Network Unit Testing in Swift](https://medium.com/flawless-app-stories/the-complete-guide-to-network-unit-testing-in-swift-db8b3ee2c327). I think that if you read it, you will acquire something new useful for the feature.

Your "mocked" class (I put with "" since it could be defined as a stub or a spy) would have the same API provided by the real one.

As I stated previously, Unit Tests should be fast and should **NOT** depend on databases, real networks requests and so on.